# $ G $ is satisfies the maximal permutizer condition if $ G $ is supersoluble?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Permutizer of a subgroup $ H $ of $ G $ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $ G $ that permute with $ H $,
i.e. $ \langle x\in G  \vert  \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle $, denoted by $ P_{G}(H) $.

A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the permutizer condition in $ G $ if $ P_{G}(H) $ strictly contains $ H $ for any subgroup $ H $ of $ G $.

A group $ G $ is said to satisfy the maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M) = G $ for any maximal subgroup $ M $
of $ G $.

This is theorem that $ G $ satisfies the permutizer condition if $ G $ is supersoluble.

Can we say $ G $ is satisfies the maximal permutizer condition if $ G $ is supersoluble ?

Comment: The third paragraph doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes. I'm editing now

Comment: I am confused. Surely if $G$ satisfies the permutizer condition then it satisfies the maximal permutizer condition. So if the theorem says that $G$ supersoluble implies $G$ satisfies permutizer condition, then that implies that it satisfies the maximal permutizer condition.